# dates being ignored when type is passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Any idea when i pass the type to the stored proecedure the dates are being ignored

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hms_GetBenefitsByDateType]
(
@id int,
@startDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@bType int
 ) 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
     SELECT        benefit.emp_no, benefit.record_id, benefit.contract_id,    benefit.career_id, benefit.date_from, benefit.date_to, benefit.benefit_type, benefit.monthly_value, benefit.benefit_provider, benefit.level_of_cover,   benefit.current_benefit, benefit.previous_monthly_cost, benefit.benefit_change_details, benefit.notes, benefit.level_description, benefit.monthly_annual, benefit.cover_level,     benefit.qualifying_reason, benefit_type.desc_
FROM benefit INNER JOIN
                     benefit_type ON benefit.benefit_type = benefit_type.code
WHERE (benefit.benefit_type = @bType) or (benefit.emp_no = @id)  and (benefit.date_from >= @startDate) and (benefit.date_to <= @EndDate)
```

where date from is 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 and date to is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
The result being produced is the following
11,4,21,123,2006-01-01 00:00:00.000,1900-01-01 00:00:00.000,3,15.00,1,2.00,1,0.00,None                                                                            ,Notes ,Children                                                    ,1,1,1,Medical Cover - Children
12,6,14,27,2013-06-21 00:00:00.000,2013-06-21 00:00:00.000,3,500.00,0,0.00,1,0.00,

Comment: how can date to less than date from?

Comment: can you explain from words what exactly you need to get from the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would go for where like this one

```
WHERE (benefit.benefit_type = @bType) or (benefit.emp_no = @id)  and ( (benefit.date_from >= @startDate) and (benefit.date_to <= (@EndDate + 1)) )
```

**#UPDATE 1**

```
   WHERE (benefit.benefit_type = @bType) or (benefit.emp_no = @id)  and ( (benefit.date_from IS NULL or benefit.date_from >= @startDate) and ( benefit.date_to IS NULL or benefit.date_to <= (@EndDate + 1)) )
```

Comment: what does the +1 do when it still needs be a null date?

Comment: if you want to be able to  send null value then you should add @startDate is null or check update

Comment: tried that the type is still over ridding is my join right for such a select

Comment: i don't get the real problem here inside your code, the problem that it gets all data even if dates are specified or what exactly?

Comment: if i pass a type say 3 which only has twos record which one falls within the dates passed it will bring back two items because their type is 3 @Alaa El-Din

Comment: try add 2 brackets for this ( (benefit.benefit_type = @bType) or (benefit.emp_no = @id) ) ,also you need this "or" or convert it to and?

Comment: when i do that it brings back no data i am executing it with this 

@return_value = [dbo].[hms_GetBenefitsByDateType]
  id = 11,
  startDate = N'2012-06-21 00:00:00.000',
  EndDate = N'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',
  bType =3

It will ignore the above as sometimes I will have cases where a benefit is not closed i removed the @ symbol as couldnt post

Comment: end date is 1900,do you have a date that ends below this date 1900??

Comment: its cause they close a benefit by selecting end date not my design but something i have to cope with

Comment: ok but what is the meaning of start date and end date if end date is always less than start date,it's meaning less + this should return nothing since the condition of "and" will always return false at any conditions since (1 or 1) =1 AND ( 1 AND 0 = 0 )=> 1 AND 0 = 0

Comment: they still have to be able to select a date in future or past to start from i no don't make since

Comment: i think what i need is to have a condition around the end date where if it is null to ignore

Comment: that's happen by adding benefit.date_to IS NULL or .... , this will return true if is null. it doesnt work fine with you?

Comment: if it's null,it will get all the fields such that inside this type and id and start with the start date,isn't that happening?

Comment: yw bro :) glad to hear this  at any time :)

Answer (score 0):

I also think your problem lies in the where condition. I think you should add more parenthesis to make the condition more clear. For ex you can try the following (*Hoping I got it right*)

```
WHERE    ((benefit.benefit_type = @bType) OR (benefit.emp_no = @id))  and
((benefit.date_from >= @startDate) and (benefit.benefit_type <= @EndDate))
```